# Documentation about "dealloc"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> In an implementation of dealloc, you should not invoke the
>   superclass’s implementation. You override this method to dispose of
>   resources other than the object’s instance variables, for example:
>
> - (void)dealloc 
>     {
>     free(myBigBlockOfMemory); 
>     }

Above says we should not invoke the superclass's implementation.  But below it says we should "incorporate superclass versions of dealloc through a message to super."  So there seems to be  some conflict between the two paragraphs. It must be due to something that I've missed. Hope somebody can explain this ...

> If you are using manual reference counting, subclasses must implement
>   their own versions of dealloc to allow the release of any additional
>   memory consumed by the object—such as dynamically allocated storage
>   for data or object instance variables owned by the deallocated object.
>   After performing the class-specific deallocation, the subclass method
>   should incorporate superclass versions of dealloc through a message to
>   super:
>
> - (void)dealloc {
>     [companion release];
>     free(myBigBlockOfMemory);
>     [super dealloc]; }

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first quote is for when automatic reference counting (ARC) is enabled, and your second quote is for when ARC is **not** enabled. ARC is a new feature provided in SDK 5.0 that eliminates much of the manual memory management that needed to be done by the programmer.

See [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html), in particular these statements:

> You may implement a dealloc method if you need to manage resources
> other than releasing instance variables. You do not have to (indeed
> you cannot) release instance variables...
>
> Custom dealloc methods in ARC do not require a call to [super dealloc]
> (it actually results in a compiler error). The chaining to super is
> automated and enforced by the compiler.