# KVO remove observing in an outlet connected object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I want to observe let's say the bounds on the view of the viewController

```
[self.view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"bounds" options:0 context:nil];
```

but how to unregister it in **dealloc**, when the **self.view is already nil**?

Note, that this question is not a duplicate
"[KVO and ARC how to removeObserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959896/kvo-and-arc-how-to-removeobserver)" as the answer doesn't handle this problem

Comment: according to the `UIViewController` life cycle and _state restoration and preservation_ policy (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) you could add an observer in the `–viewWillAppear:` method and you'd need to remove that in the `–viewDidDisappear:` method.

Comment: allright, but this may concernt the NSViewController, which doesn't have viewWillAppear: viewDidDisappear:

Comment: probably I don't understand your problem then... regarding the observers are always _weak_ references in `ARC`, you should not worry about removing them before the observed object is released permanently. which means, when your `self.view` is `nil`, the observer has removed implicitly already. can you please clarify what your goal is here actually?

Comment: the problem is, that KVO doesn't use ARC and keeps an unsafe reference... so it needs to be explicitly removed