# Removing observers in post-ARC Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing, nsnotifications, automatic-ref-counting

So far I have been removing observers (notifications or KVO) in the dealloc. Since dealloc is gone in ARC, what's the recommended way to do this?

Comment: Note that [it’s usually better if you can send -removeObserver:… before -dealloc gets called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927/in-cocoa-do-i-need-to-remove-an-object-from-receiving-kvo-notifications-when-dea/14054#14054).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

-dealloc is not gone under ARC. The ivar-releasing and super-calling aspects are handled automatically, allowing you to omit it if that's all you were going to do, but you should still implement it for other things if it makes sense to do so.

Comment: Yep, iOS 5.0 documentation says "If you deallocate an object that is observing notifications, you need to tell the notification center to stop sending it notifications." so -dealloc method will continue to be needed.

Comment: @Catfish_Man Are you sure dealloc still gets called? I made some tests and mine never gets called.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.dealloc

Comment: But in the same place (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#misc.special_methods.dealloc) I also read: "Rationale: even though ARC destroys instance variables automatically, there are still legitimate reasons to write a dealloc method, such as freeing non-retainable resources. Failing to call [super dealloc] in such a method is nearly always a bug. "

Comment: If I set the object *posting* the notifications to `nil`, do I need to remove observers watching it, or is that cleaned up automatically by ARC?

Comment: Automatic observer unregistration is only done under GC, not ARC

Comment: I'm confused though, under ARC I can't call [super dealloc] ?

Comment: ARC will call [super dealloc] for you if necessary.