# No longer necessary to remove notification observers in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter, weak-references

In this [post](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com.es/2010/12/objective-c-memory-management-garbage.html) about Garbage Collection the author states:

> in Mac OS X 10.6 and later NSNotificationCenter is weak referenced so
>   you no longer need do to the following in your code
>
> ```
> [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
>       name:kObservationName
>       object:nil];
> ```

Is this officially documented somewhere? The documentation of [`removeObserver:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/removeObserver%3a) still says:

> Be sure to invoke this method (or removeObserver:name:object:) before
>   notificationObserver or any object specified in
>   addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.

Comment: This SO answer also states that it's not necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34513/143378

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a **Garbage Collected** Application, then it is true that you don't need to unregister an object for receiving observations or notifications.

But Garbage Collection is deprecated now, and not something you should be using for new projects.

If you are using **ARC** or **MRC**, then you still need to remove objects. And the best place to do that is usually in the `dealloc` method.

Comment: Doesn't ARC support zeroing weak references now? Seems NSNotificationCenter could be weak-referencing under ARC?

Comment: It does support zeroing weak references, but you still need to remove observations yourself.

Comment: Not really. It's in there somewhere. But the reasoning goes: ARC only manages object lifetimes, nothing else.